# gmsh, minimum distance between point and surface, to find the nearest surface

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to automatically set all the Points `In` the nearest surface.
As I didn't find a simple way to do it, I'm trying to manually find the nearest surface for the needed points.
Is it possible to calculate the minimum distance from a Point and a Surface?
so that I can call

```
Point{n} In Surface {id_nearest};
```

and get a mesh node for that geometry  Point?

My tries involved the use of `Field.Attractor` and `FacesList`, creating a `Field` for each `Surface` and then trying to find in which field the Point is with `isInside`. But this seems harder than it likely is and didn't work.